# How to solve NetStandard and .NetFrameworkVersion compatability issue?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have been given an assignment to complete. It was written in 2012 and is based on Visual Studio 2012. I am trying to complete it but am struggling due to not finding a solution to the following error:

> Warning
>   Project '..\Common\Common.csproj' targets 'netstandard2.0'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'

I am currently using Visual Studio 2019. Is there a way I can fix this? Or should I just try and download an older version?

Thank you in advance!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: VS 2019 is backwards compatible / supports projects down to .NET 1.1. I suggest to stick with VS2019 as there are in my opinion many advantages over VS2012. .NET 4.5 is not compatible with _netstandard2.0_. So your _Common_ project should also target .NET (eg 4.5). Configure this in the project properties.

Comment: There is no point in still targeting 4.5, it reached end-of-life three and a half year ago and there is no machine left that you yourself can support that hasn't been updated to at least 4.7.  So simply bump up the target framework version and solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you :) I had to change it to target 1.1 as I could not find a 4.5. But it is working now!